# How can I automate the checkout of an excel spreadsheet from a sharepoint document library, edit the spreadsheet, and check it back in?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a couple of hundred excel spreadsheets that are stored in a SharePoint 2010 document library.

A good many of these spreadsheets have hard coded URLs that need to be updated to new URLs based on some re-structuring of our SharePoint site.

I would like to iterate through all of the spreadsheets, open them and do a search and replace and then write them back into SharePoint.

For the record, I already know how to iterate the excel spreadsheets in SharePoint (creating reference to SPFile) and run the checkout and checking commands.

I am almost very comfortable with doing the OLE Automation of Excel to do the find and replace.

I am struggling with how to bridge the gap between the two.  After I grab a reference to a file and check it out, how can I do ole automation on it?  Normally I believe that to open a reference to a file I would need a file path but even if I check out with the "use local" option there is not a file created into the file system (and even if there is I am not convinced that it would work to work with the temp file.)

It seems that I should be able to load it from a stream into a VBA Excel Automation object but I am not sure how.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you show us what you've built so far and tell us which part is missing?

Comment: I just looked at the VBA object model and notice that the workbook object has a Checkout method.  And the description is "Copies the workbook from a server to a local computer for editing"...just what I was looking for.  If that works I will post the code into my answer.  Seth

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you build this tool as a Console Application, which you run on the SharePoint server. In the Console Application code:

1. Use the SharePoint object model to check-out the file
2. Use the .Net [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method to download the file to your local system
3. Run your Automation code
4. Use the SharePoint object model to upload and check-in the modified file

I should point out that some server administrators will not allow Automation code to run on the server itself. In this case, run the Console Application on a client machine and use the SharePoint Lists webservice to do the check-in and check-out.